# Angular-cli is not getting installed on ubuntu20

Tags: ubuntu, angular-cli

I had already installed Angular with it's requirement in 2021 and it was working fine.But this time in 2022 when I started using it again ,it gave some error, and suggested downgrading node and npm.So I tried to re-install everything.I uninstalled everything and then installed nodejs and npm successfully but Angular cli is not getting installed.

I used these commands:-
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install nodejs
sudo apt install npm

Till, here commands worked fine.
but when I ran command, sudo npm instal-g @angular/cli

It gave me errors:-
[Error of Angular Cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0U57.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your command is not proper. Please use the following.

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```